# Simple GLSL shader results in "1: '€' : unexpected token" compilation error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a very simple shader here:

```
#version 460

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout (location = 0) out vec3 outPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(inPos.x, inPos.y, inPos.z, 1.0);
    outPos = inPos;
}
```

and compiled the shader using the command:

```
glslangValidator -V -G -o triangle.vert.spv triangle.vert
```

and the compiler turned 3 errors:

```
error : #version: ES shaders for SPIR-V require version 310 or higher
error : Source\Shaders\triangle.vert:1: '€' : unexpected token
error : Source\Shaders\triangle.vert:1: '' : compilation terminated
```

It seems that the compiler is having trouble reading the very first line of the code. I am very sure I don't include a euro sign in this, and the syntax should be correct.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this problem was indeed caused by very first bytes of the file - BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

I am using Jetbrains Rider, for me the fix was `File Encoding -> Remove BOM`.